# In sys.version is Clang as compiler, not python, What can I do?

Tags: python-3.x, vim, clang

I'm using python 3.8.3 with vim and MacOs Mojave, I was making a common script in python and when I tried run it, it shows a syntax error with `+=` operator, this have never happened before, when I checked `sys.version` in both vim and the console with the `python3` command it says that I'm using Clang to compile code, yesterday I modified my `.vimrc` a lot and no more and I don't now if that's related.

I tried running other programms with the same `+=` operator and it works.

This is the python3 console result:

```
Python 3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]'
>>>
```

This is the code with the problem:

```
#coding=utf-8

def sum_user(user, times, operator):

    counter=0

    for i in times:
        contar+=1
        if counter<times:
            resultado=user+=1
        else:
            break
    return result
```

Comment: `resultado = user+=1` is illegal. `user+=1` is a statement, so it can't be on the right side of an assignment. You'll need to break that line up.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I fixed it and it worked, but is it normal to have Clang as python "compiler"?, I don't understand that

Comment: IIRC, `sys.version_info` in _cleaner_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sys.version` field contains information about the version of Python and the C compiler used to build it.  The `python` binary and the corresponding shared libraries are written in C, so some C compiler must be used to compile it.

On some platforms, such as Windows, the compiler used may contain relevant information, since it's possible to build for either the Microsoft runtime or the GNU runtime and any extension modules must be compiled against the same runtime.

Your Python code is not compiled with the C compiler, but the Python runtime.  The C compiler is simply there for informative reasons, and if you don't care about which one was used, then you can just ignore it.